# How to slide bootstrap div's offscreen?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Make leftmost item(item 1) invisible by sliding elements right to it towards left and show another element (item 5) at rightmost with same slide effect.

Div's should slide left-right on large screen and up-down in small screens.

Solutions to this problem included div's that were not columns of bootstrap row.

How to sove it if bootstrap's row-column are used to make design responsive?

Edit 1:I want to do like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/MABZj/1/) but when div's are bootstrap columns.

Edit 1.1: Is it at all possible to achieve required functionality while using bootstrap?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6", "item 7"];
  // array containing all items
  
  $("#left_btn").on('click', function(e) {
    // slide items to the left i.e. make leftmost item(item 1) invisible by sliding elements right to it towards left and show another element(item 5) at rightmost with same slide effect
  });

  $("#right_btn").on('click', function(e) {
    // just reverse of left button
  });
})
```

```css
.col-sm-2 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- custom css styles file page.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="delete.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jquery-ui.js  library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn" id="left_btn">
     Shift left
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div id="item1" class="item">
          Item 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div id="item2" class="item">
          Item 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div id="item3" class="item">
          Item 3
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div id="item4" class="item">
          Item 4
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="right_btn">
        <button class="btn">
     Shift Right
    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or just requesting free code?

Comment: I want to slide bootstrap div's and there is not any clue to how to do that. Bootstrap columns are fixed and if I apply slide left to one column then whole row will get shifted leaving blank space at right that's why I asked here.Some problems are conceptual, they need to be understand before trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *«Some problems are conceptual, they need to be understand before trying.»*

I aggree with this. Let's go for a full explanation try out.

First, you *«want to slide bootstrap div's and there is not any clue to how to do that.»*. I assume you searched the documentation to say this... Anyway you are right, because the *"bootstrap div's"* you are talking about aren't intended to do this. They're intended to "auto-adjust" themselves to the device width based on a CSS [**Grid System**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works) you just have to implement.

Those divs aren't *"fixed"*, they are *"floating"*. That means if they cannot fit in the remaining space of a row, based on ["break points"](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-tiers), they will float down.

**So you have a couple calculations to make.**
You will base those on the "measurements" you will get from the rendered page and you **will have to re-do those** calculations on `resize`, since mobiles have landscape and portrait orientations.

Using only the `.col-*` classes is the exact opposite of the behavior you wish to create, which has a concept name : **Carousel**. There is plenty Carousel plugins already coded to hold all kind of content (Images, videos, text...) and keeping it all "responsive". So if you want to use Bootstrap for responsiveness, I suggest you use a fully tested and well reviewed plugin.

---

The example below is just for you to understand the concept. If you try to use that code with hope you'll have no bugs... Please, don't ask me to fix them when you'll discover one (matter of minutes).

---

**So here's the concept of a Carousel:**

Imagine a piece of paper in which your cut out a rectangular hole.
Then a second piece of paper, same height as the hole, but much wider.

You will then use those two by sliding the small one in the "window" the hole makes in the big paper.

An image worth a thousand word, they say... So what about a video?
[Slide Out Birthday Card](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9t_wGl1osY)

Now, that is supposed to be clear enought.

So you have to have a div for the "hole" and a div for the sliding paper.
Let see the code and comment with now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Get our element count.
  var carouselItemCount = $(".carousel-item").length;
  // An index to always know the sliding container position.
  var moveIndex = 0;
  // Always have 3 elements in view.
  var maxMove = carouselItemCount-2;

  // Function to set all elements widths.
  function setWidths(){
    // Get the window witdh
    var WWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log("WWidth: "+WWidth);

    // Are we in a Small device?
    var SM = false;
    if(WWidth<768){
      SM = true;
    }
    // If yes, wewant to show 3 elements anyway,
    // so we can't rely on the .col-sm-2 width
    // because it is equal to 100% of the window.
    if(SM){
      var SM2width = WWidth/4;
    }else{
      var SM2width = $(".col-sm-2").first().outerWidth(true);
    }
    $(".carousel-item").width(SM2width);

    // Get the items widths with and without border/margin
    var carouselItemWidth = $(".carousel-item").width();
    var carouselItemOuterWidth = $(".carousel-item").outerWidth(true);

    // Set carousel item margin (remainder of caroussel-inner - 3* items);
    var carouselInnerVisibleSpaceLeft = $(".carousel-inner").parent("div").innerWidth() - (carouselItemWidth * 3);
    $(".carousel-item").css({"margin": "0 "+carouselInnerVisibleSpaceLeft/8+"px"});

    // Get the new items outer widths (we just changed it)
    var NewCarouselItemOuterWidth = $(".carousel-item").outerWidth(true);

    // Get the items border, as it causes an offset issue.
    var border = parseInt($(".item").css("border"));
    console.log("border: "+border);

    // Set animate postion (needed on resize)
    $(".carousel-inner").animate({"left":-moveIndex * (NewCarouselItemOuterWidth + border)},0);


    // ========== Movements triggered by user

    // LEFT
    $("#left_btn").off('click').on('click', function(e) {

      console.log("Click left");
      moveIndex++;
      if(moveIndex<maxMove){
        $(".carousel-inner").animate({"left":-moveIndex * (NewCarouselItemOuterWidth + border)},800);
      }else{
        console.log("full left reached");
        // Canccel that moveIndex addition.
        moveIndex--;
      }
    });

    // RIGHT
    $("#right_btn").off('click').on('click', function(e) {

      console.log("Click right");
      moveIndex--;
      if(moveIndex>=0){
        $(".carousel-inner").animate({"left":-moveIndex * (NewCarouselItemOuterWidth + border)},800);
      }else{
        console.log("full right reached");
        // Canccel that moveIndex substraction.
        moveIndex++;
      }
    });

  } // setWidths

  // Set all elements width on load and get the carousel item widths needed for movements.
  setWidths();
  // Set all elements width on resize.
  $(window).on("resize", setWidths);

});  // Ready
```

In this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KXddWv?editors=0011), you will see the code in action.
You will also see the modifications made on the HTML and CSS.
*(I thought it was not relevant enougth to post here)*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having a hard time getting it started. Unfortunately Bootstrap divs aren't really made for this, but here is an example of a div that is able to shift to the right on/off the screen without the use of Bootstrap. I'm sure you can take this example and figure out whatever you need to do from here.

```js
// Config box
$('.spin-icon').click(function() {
  $('.theme-config-box').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
/* Controls box */

.theme-config {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.theme-config-box {
  margin-right: -300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.theme-config-box.show {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.spin-icon {
  background: #1ab394;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 7px 10px 7px 13px;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skin-settings {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background: #f3f3f4;
}

.skin-settings .title {
  background: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.setings-item {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.setings-item .switch {
  float: right;
}


/* SWITCHES */

.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 54px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #1AB394;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 7px;
  background-color: #1AB394;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 7px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #919191;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #1AB394;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 36px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="theme-config">
  <div class="theme-config-box">
    <div class="spin-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="skin-settings">
      <div class="title">Options<br>
        <small style="text-transform: none;font-weight: 400">Change settings here.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="setings-item">
        <span>
     Option A
   </span>

        <div class="switch">
          <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="optionA" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="optionA">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="optionA">
  <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="setings-item">
        <span>
     Option B
   </span>

        <div class="switch">
          <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="optionB" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="optionB">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="optionB">
  <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="setings-item">
        <span>
     Option C
   </span>

        <div class="switch">
          <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="optionC" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="optionC">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="optionC">
  <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but here you haven't put div's in bootstrap columns.I want to slide bootstrap columns or div's inside them.